# Swift playground result wrong position

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

In Swift Playgrounds (Xcode) the result appears too low in the editor, is this a bug in Xcode?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue appears to be related to the plugin: https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCXcodeEditorInset

I've contacted the author about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to recreate your issue. Have you tried restarting Xcode? Are you using a beta version?

It looks like there is something on line 27 in your playground. Have you tried highlighting and deleting it?

[image]

Comment: Thats just a blank line after the background color setting, removing it doesn't help. Using Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014), also I've tried restarting Xcode and that didn't help either unfortunately.